# Integrating a sphere by discs vs shells (spherical coordinates)

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I am getting very confused about the following. Let's say I want to find the volume of a sphere. I can start with a circle having circumference $2\pi R\cos\theta$. I can multiply by $R d\theta$ and integrate to get $4\pi R^2$ as the surface area. Then, I can convert $R$ to $r$ integrate from $0$ to $R$. to get the volume. That makes sense to me.

Now, however, let's try to do the same thing with discs. I have a disk with area $\pi R^2 \sin^2\theta$. It seems like I should add a bunch of discs with height $R d\theta$, but that doesn't work. I really need to add discs with height $R\sin\theta d\theta$ (in order to get it to come out right), yet I do not have a good understanding of why. It isn't 100% obvious to me why $R \sin\theta d\theta$ is the correct height. I can sort of see where the pieces of it come from, but certainly could not draw a picture, for example.

Answer (score 0):

with the discs the area is $\pi r^2 \cos^2 \theta$, and the thickness is $r \cos\theta d\theta$ so you want:
$$
\frac{V}{\pi r^3} = \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \cos^3 \theta d\theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}(1-\sin^2 \theta)\cos \theta
$$

Comment: I never had any real doubt of either of those things. (Though I think you meant $\pi r^2 \cos^2\theta$ for the area. My confusion comes from *why* $r\cos\theta d\theta$ is the height. I can describe qualitatively why it should be about right (near the top of the sphere $r d\theta$ is a poor approximation for the height and $r\sin\theta d\theta$ seems to fix this problem, but I cannot picture rigorously--i.e. drawing triangles or something-- *why* this is the solution). Do you have insight into that?

Comment: thx for spotting the typo. if the radius vector from the origin to a point on the circumference makes an angle $\theta$ with the 'horizontal', then the tangent at that point, being perpendicular to the radius vector, makes an angle $\theta$ with the 'vertical'. so to get the thicknesss of the disc you multiply by $\cos \theta$ - that's really all there is to it!

Comment: Wonderful! With that hint I was able to draw the triangle that I wanted. $R d\theta$ is the hypotenuse and, thanks to your hint, I saw that $\theta$ was the angle opposite the height of the triangle, so basic trig gave the desired result! Thank you for the hint! I had never realized that integrating discs was so much less obvious than integrating shells (hence, everyone choosing to use the shell method).

Comment: that bit of geometry has an interesting history! using the same insight Archimedes showed that the surface area of a sphere is equal to the area (of the curved surface) of the (smallest) cylinder which contains it. here the effect of contraction of the radius with latitude is exactly compensated for by the iincrease due to the slant. the cylinder area straightforwardly gives $2\pi r \times 2r$ so the $4\pi r^2$ was an easy deduction